# Target Membership in React Native

Tags: react-native, targeting

I am involved to a project which is targeting multiple clients. We have to handle different client needs and so it can happen that a client wants to fully change a page in the application or they would like a different logic behind the screen. And of course we don't want to include one client's specific code to another code base, so separate our code with a kind of global variables is not an option.

On iOS it was really straightforward that we had to add a new target and select files to the target membership.

How we should handle it within a React Native project?
I found many articles about react-native-config, but it is just about the global variables, URLs and so on.